# How to set background color for all ListView items

Tags: android, android-listview

I have ListView where some of items will have gray background color. I would like, on some action, to set  white background color for all items in ListView.

How to do this?

Comment: maybe use custom adapter

Comment: if you are defining a custom layout for your row views just use `android:background="@android:color/gray`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could interate through the child views of your ListView and set their background color:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View listItem = listView.getChildAt(i);
    listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add: android:background="#FFFFFF"

Comment: The simplest way.